# prevent duplicate choice in dropdowns with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have 5 dropdowns, named sample1 through sample5... each dropdown contains the same list of choices (populated from my SQL with ASP), but I need to stop them from submitting duplicates.  All 5 need to be different.  However, 0 is acceptable as a value for each of them (blank).

```
FREE Sample Choice 1: <select name="sample1" onChange="JavaScript:FOSamples()">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="FOABSOLUTETULIP">Fragrance Oil: Absolute Tulip BBW Type</option>
<option value="FOAFRICANMUSK">Fragrance Oil: African Musk</option>
<option value="FOALMOND">Fragrance Oil: Almond</option>
<option value="FOAMAR">Fragrance Oil: Amaretto</option>
<option value="FOAMBER">Fragrance Oil: Amber</option>
<option value="FOAMBERROM">Fragrance Oil: Amber Romance Victoria's Secret Type</option>
<option value="FOANAIS">Fragrance Oil: Anais Anais Type</option>
<option value="FOANGEL">Fragrance Oil: Angel Type</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEBLOS">Fragrance Oil: Apple Blossoms</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEJACK">Fragrance Oil: Apple Jack & Peel</option>
<option value="FOAPPLESP">Fragrance Oil: Apple Spice</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEOAK">Fragrance Oil: Apples & Oak</option>
<option value="FOAPRICOT">Fragrance Oil: Apricot</option>
<option value="FOAPRICOTPEAR">Fragrance Oil: Apricot & Pear Yankee Type</option>
<option value="FOAPRCREME">Fragrance Oil: Apricot Creme</option>
<option value="FOAQUAREEF">Fragrance Oil: Aqua Reef Old Spice Type</option>
<option value="FOARABIANMUSK">Fragrance Oil: Arabian Musk</option>
<option value="FOASIANPEAR">Fragrance Oil: Asian Pear</option>
<option value="FOASIANPLUM">Fragrance Oil: Asian Plum Blossom</option>
<option value="FOAUTUMNWOODS">Fragrance Oil: Autumn Woods</option>
</select><br>
FREE Sample Choice 2: <select name="sample2" onChange="JavaScript:FOSamples()">

<option value="0"></option>
<option value="FOABSOLUTETULIP">Fragrance Oil: Absolute Tulip BBW Type</option>
<option value="FOAFRICANMUSK">Fragrance Oil: African Musk</option>
<option value="FOALMOND">Fragrance Oil: Almond</option>
<option value="FOAMAR">Fragrance Oil: Amaretto</option>
<option value="FOAMBER">Fragrance Oil: Amber</option>
<option value="FOAMBERROM">Fragrance Oil: Amber Romance Victoria's Secret Type</option>
<option value="FOANAIS">Fragrance Oil: Anais Anais Type</option>
<option value="FOANGEL">Fragrance Oil: Angel Type</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEBLOS">Fragrance Oil: Apple Blossoms</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEJACK">Fragrance Oil: Apple Jack & Peel</option>
<option value="FOAPPLESP">Fragrance Oil: Apple Spice</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEOAK">Fragrance Oil: Apples & Oak</option>
<option value="FOAPRICOT">Fragrance Oil: Apricot</option>
<option value="FOAPRICOTPEAR">Fragrance Oil: Apricot & Pear Yankee Type</option>
<option value="FOAPRCREME">Fragrance Oil: Apricot Creme</option>
<option value="FOAQUAREEF">Fragrance Oil: Aqua Reef Old Spice Type</option>
<option value="FOARABIANMUSK">Fragrance Oil: Arabian Musk</option>
<option value="FOASIANPEAR">Fragrance Oil: Asian Pear</option>
<option value="FOASIANPLUM">Fragrance Oil: Asian Plum Blossom</option>
<option value="FOAUTUMNWOODS">Fragrance Oil: Autumn Woods</option>
</select><br>

FREE Sample Choice 3: <select name="sample3" onChange="JavaScript:FOSamples()">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="FOABSOLUTETULIP">Fragrance Oil: Absolute Tulip BBW Type</option>
<option value="FOAFRICANMUSK">Fragrance Oil: African Musk</option>
<option value="FOALMOND">Fragrance Oil: Almond</option>
<option value="FOAMAR">Fragrance Oil: Amaretto</option>
<option value="FOAMBER">Fragrance Oil: Amber</option>
<option value="FOAMBERROM">Fragrance Oil: Amber Romance Victoria's Secret Type</option>
<option value="FOANAIS">Fragrance Oil: Anais Anais Type</option>
<option value="FOANGEL">Fragrance Oil: Angel Type</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEBLOS">Fragrance Oil: Apple Blossoms</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEJACK">Fragrance Oil: Apple Jack & Peel</option>
<option value="FOAPPLESP">Fragrance Oil: Apple Spice</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEOAK">Fragrance Oil: Apples & Oak</option>
<option value="FOAPRICOT">Fragrance Oil: Apricot</option>
<option value="FOAPRICOTPEAR">Fragrance Oil: Apricot & Pear Yankee Type</option>
<option value="FOAPRCREME">Fragrance Oil: Apricot Creme</option>
<option value="FOAQUAREEF">Fragrance Oil: Aqua Reef Old Spice Type</option>
<option value="FOARABIANMUSK">Fragrance Oil: Arabian Musk</option>
<option value="FOASIANPEAR">Fragrance Oil: Asian Pear</option>
<option value="FOASIANPLUM">Fragrance Oil: Asian Plum Blossom</option>
<option value="FOAUTUMNWOODS">Fragrance Oil: Autumn Woods</option>
</select><br>

FREE Sample Choice 4: <select name="sample4" onChange="JavaScript:FOSamples()">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="FOABSOLUTETULIP">Fragrance Oil: Absolute Tulip BBW Type</option>
<option value="FOAFRICANMUSK">Fragrance Oil: African Musk</option>
<option value="FOALMOND">Fragrance Oil: Almond</option>
<option value="FOAMAR">Fragrance Oil: Amaretto</option>
<option value="FOAMBER">Fragrance Oil: Amber</option>
<option value="FOAMBERROM">Fragrance Oil: Amber Romance Victoria's Secret Type</option>
<option value="FOANAIS">Fragrance Oil: Anais Anais Type</option>
<option value="FOANGEL">Fragrance Oil: Angel Type</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEBLOS">Fragrance Oil: Apple Blossoms</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEJACK">Fragrance Oil: Apple Jack & Peel</option>
<option value="FOAPPLESP">Fragrance Oil: Apple Spice</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEOAK">Fragrance Oil: Apples & Oak</option>
<option value="FOAPRICOT">Fragrance Oil: Apricot</option>
<option value="FOAPRICOTPEAR">Fragrance Oil: Apricot & Pear Yankee Type</option>
<option value="FOAPRCREME">Fragrance Oil: Apricot Creme</option>
<option value="FOAQUAREEF">Fragrance Oil: Aqua Reef Old Spice Type</option>
<option value="FOARABIANMUSK">Fragrance Oil: Arabian Musk</option>
<option value="FOASIANPEAR">Fragrance Oil: Asian Pear</option>
<option value="FOASIANPLUM">Fragrance Oil: Asian Plum Blossom</option>
<option value="FOAUTUMNWOODS">Fragrance Oil: Autumn Woods</option>
</select><br>

FREE Sample Choice 5: <select name="sample5" onChange="JavaScript:FOSamples()">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="FOABSOLUTETULIP">Fragrance Oil: Absolute Tulip BBW Type</option>
<option value="FOAFRICANMUSK">Fragrance Oil: African Musk</option>
<option value="FOALMOND">Fragrance Oil: Almond</option>
<option value="FOAMAR">Fragrance Oil: Amaretto</option>
<option value="FOAMBER">Fragrance Oil: Amber</option>
<option value="FOAMBERROM">Fragrance Oil: Amber Romance Victoria's Secret Type</option>
<option value="FOANAIS">Fragrance Oil: Anais Anais Type</option>
<option value="FOANGEL">Fragrance Oil: Angel Type</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEBLOS">Fragrance Oil: Apple Blossoms</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEJACK">Fragrance Oil: Apple Jack & Peel</option>
<option value="FOAPPLESP">Fragrance Oil: Apple Spice</option>
<option value="FOAPPLEOAK">Fragrance Oil: Apples & Oak</option>
<option value="FOAPRICOT">Fragrance Oil: Apricot</option>
<option value="FOAPRICOTPEAR">Fragrance Oil: Apricot & Pear Yankee Type</option>
<option value="FOAPRCREME">Fragrance Oil: Apricot Creme</option>
<option value="FOAQUAREEF">Fragrance Oil: Aqua Reef Old Spice Type</option>
<option value="FOARABIANMUSK">Fragrance Oil: Arabian Musk</option>
<option value="FOASIANPEAR">Fragrance Oil: Asian Pear</option>
<option value="FOASIANPLUM">Fragrance Oil: Asian Plum Blossom</option>
<option value="FOAUTUMNWOODS">Fragrance Oil: Autumn Woods</option>
</select><br>
```

[5 Dropdowns Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Kateriana/nDGu8/)

The dropdowns are identical so maybe removing the option from the other 4 when selected would be better?  I really am not sure of the capabilities of JavaScript (my expertise is ASP and SQL).  Should I do ONE dropdown and limit it to 5 Ctrl+click selections?  I went ahead and started a fiddle with this layout too.

[Single Multiple Dropdown](http://jsfiddle.net/Kateriana/N4uHd/1/)

I'm not sure which option my boss would prefer.  We use the 5 dropdowns now, but maybe the other one would be cleaner.  Do you have problems with people not understanding how to select mutliple items?

Can one of you JavaScript gurus write my FOSamples function to work?  Is OnChange the correct javascript to use?  Right now, the office has to just watch for duplicates and manually remove and replace with something else.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function FOSamples() {

    }
-->
</script>
```

Mahalo!

Comment: I personnaly like this jQuery plugin http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#selectedlist

Comment: Yes, use the single multiple dropdown. You still can progressively enhance it, e.g. with [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty pure JS implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/nDGu8/8/

```
var old_values = {}; // memorize old value of select before it was changed

// to be called with an event listener, i.e. this refers to the changed <select>
function FOSamples() {
    if (old_values[this.name]) { // if there were options disabled, re-enable them
        // find all <options value=OLD_VALUE>
        var s = document.querySelectorAll('option[value="' + old_values[this.name] + '"]');
        [].forEach.call(s, function (option) {
            option.disabled = false;
        });
    }
    // find all <options value=NEW_VALUE>
    var s = document.querySelectorAll('option[value="' + this.value + '"]');
    [].forEach.call(s, function (option) {
        if (option.parentNode !== this) {
            // if it is not the <select> the user has just changed, disable the <option>
            option.disabled = true;
        }
    }, this);
    // memorize value
    old_values[this.name] = this.value;
}
```

The whole implementation would be easier to implement using JQuery.
And if you consider using JQuery, best use the widged @btoueg mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I've never worked with JQuery, can one of you explain the difference?  Kay, is this for the 5 dropdowns or the one, multi?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with jQuery and the multiselect widget: http://jsfiddle.net/YQZw8/2

```
$(function(){
    // make sure no option is selected by default
    $("select").prop("selectedIndex", -1);
    // add "multiple select" widget, and set max options to 5
    $("select").multiselect({
      click: function(e){
        if( $(this).multiselect("widget").find("input:checked").length > 5 ){
          return false;
        }
      }
    }); 
});
```

You'll need to include some javascript and CSS though.